# Display specific error in fetch api in js

Tags: javascript

When I am using the Fetch API I use the catch method to error. When I hit any wrong command it only show error occurred. How to display the correct error in the main screen using catch

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.